# Remove duplicates from list of string and also remove the key value

Tags: vb.net, filtering

I am looking to remove duplicated items from a list of string I have. 
I have 2 text files. One with with all the results I have and the other are the results that are finished.

I wish to remove the finished results from the file that contain all my results. So far I have tried the distinct function, but this will always leave a not-duplicated string as well.

Is there a way to use the distinct function for this and also remove the item that was duplicated?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. This site is for questions regarding specific issues with existing code. As it stands, your question is off-topic because you don't explain what behaviour you're  getting and what errors you get and on what line they occur. Don't let negative votes or votes to close put you off though. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2) function:

```
Dim results = {"a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "d"}
Dim finished = {"a", "c"}

Dim remainder = results.Except(finished)

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", remainder))
```

outputs:

> b, d

Unless you wanted to keep both occurrences of "d".

Answer (score 0):

You use the `.RemoveAll` function in the string class, in which takes a function and removes all matches for a given condition, like the following.

```
var x = new List<string>() { "a", "a", "b", "c" };
x.RemoveAll(a => string.Equals(a, "a"));
```

This code removes both instances, in this example, of `a` in the list.

Or of you have a collection to match against for removal:

```
var collToRemove = new List<string>() { "a" };
x.RemoveAll(a => collToRemove.Contains(a));
```

Comment: In this instance "a" is just 1 string. Lets say I have 1 million results that I want to check. I could loop through it with a for each, but would that be more effective than perhaps another method?

Comment: If you had a collection in which you were matching, you could just change the `string.Equals` into a `coll.Contains(a)`

Comment: This is a vb.net question not C#.